# Set background color of textArea in Summernote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, summernote

I am integrating [Summernote](http://summernote.org/) in the jdorn [json-editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor). I have it all working but I need to be able to set the background color of the `textArea` Summernote is using. There is apparently no API to do this in Summernote (or I am missing it). I have a "brute force" method (below) using `jquery` but that changes every instance of Summernote on the page.

Is there an existing way to do this in Summernote – or a jquery way to target an individual instance (which I can access easily). I haven't used jquery much so this may be a really basic question.

---

```
        var newCss = {};
        newCss.backgroundColor = #000000;
        $('.note-editable').css(newCss);
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this through using the `onInit` callback event and digging into the event target to access the `editable` property – that is the `div` which contains the editable text.

```
         onInit: function (e) {
            self.editable = e.editable[0]

            var bgColor = self.jsoneditor.root.getValue().options.default_bg_color;
            self.editable.style.backgroundColor = bgColor
          },
```